# Google play app signing steps

Tags: java, android

I tried to upload an APK , but I cannot use google play app signing, so can you please provide me with the whole steps from the very beginning.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to self-sign your app, before using google play app signing. You can self-sign your app using [APK Signer or Jar Signer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing/signing-the-app-package/manually-signing-the-apk/) and then you have align your application using [Zip Align](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign).

If you have used Android Studio for building your application, you can follow these steps [App Signing using Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key).

*Steps to manually sign your Application*

**1. Install the signer tool**

*Install the apksigner*

Installation should be from the [Android Build Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools). Download and find the apksigner inside the buildtools directory.

*Install the jarsigner*

Jarsigner by default it comes with jdk. Install [jdk](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and find jarsigner there.

**2. Create a key pair using keytool.**

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore xample.keystore -alias publishingdoc -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

It asks for your details, like First Name, Last Name, etc.., Based on the Android SDK, you have to sign the app using apksigner or jarsigner.

**3. Signing and aligning the Application**

**When using jarsigner to sign the application**

It is necessary to sign the application first and then use zip align.

Jarsigner

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore xample.keystore mono.samples.helloworld.apk publishingdoc
```

Zipalign

```
zipalign -f -v 4 mono.samples.helloworld-unsigned.apk helloworld.apk
```

**When using apksigner for signing**

It is necessary to align the application before signing.

ZipAlign

```
zipalign -f -v 4 mono.samples.helloworld-unsigned.apk helloworld.apk
```

APKSigner - Remember APKsigner is located in the buildtools directory inside Android Studio. Go to the directory and execute the following command.

```
apksigner sign --ks xample.keystore --ks-key-alias publishingdoc mono.samples.helloworld.apk
```

[Reference 1 - Tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing/signing-the-app-package/manually-signing-the-apk/)

[Reference 2 - Apksigner](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner)

[Reference 3 - Zipalign](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign)

Answer (score 0):

It a pretty lengthy proccess which will look ugly here follow the documentation link below for the step by step process, which will give you different method to sign your app apart prom the **Play Store** signing

**DOCUMENTATION**:https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Answer (score 0):

> Create an app

1. Go to your Play Console >https://play.google.com/apps/publish/
2. Select **All applications** > **Create application.**
3. Using the drop down menu, select a default language and add a title for your app. Type the name of your app as you want it to appear in Google Play.
4. Create your app's store listing, take the content rating questionnaire, and set up pricing & distribution.
   for more: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en